# React native expo .env file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, dotenv

I've created a react native app with expo.I installed the dotenv package, I want to make a .env file and use it but I get an error saying
`Unable to resolve @env from ...`. I've read a bunch of articles and blog post about using .env files in expo but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
Here is the code:

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "module:react-native-dotenv"],
  };
};
```

.env

```
PORT=8082
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {View,Text} from "react-native";

import {PORT} from "@env";

export function App() {
return (
  <View><Text>{PORT}</Text></View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting `"module:react-native-dotenv"` in `plugins` like so:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [["module:react-native-dotenv"]],
  };
};
```

Don't forget to restart your expo/npm server after.